# Laravel Database information different styles

Tags: php, css, laravel

The fallowing code display the news from my page as `ul` list

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
            @foreach($news as $k => $item)

                @if ($k == 1)
                    @if ($ad = $options->getHomeNewsAd())
                        <div id="ad">{{ $ad }}</div>
                    @endif
                @endif

                <li>
                    <figure class="figure">
                    <figcaption>{{ $item->created_at }} <a href="{{ Helpers::url($item->title, $item->id, 'news') }}">{{ $item->title }}</a></figcaption>
                        <a href="{{ Helpers::url($item->title, $item->id, 'news') }}"><img src="{{ $item->image }}" alt="{{ $item->title }}" class="img-responsive"></a>

                       <figcaption-news>{{{ Helpers::shrtString($item->body, 400) }}}</figcaption>

                    </figure>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
```

Now I have for every news entry the same `li` class style but I want to change every second entry `li` or `div` style like that example

```
 <li>
                    <figure class="figure">
                    <figcaption>{{ $item->created_at }} <a href="{{ Helpers::url($item->title, $item->id, 'news') }}">{{ $item->title }}</a></figcaption>
                        <a href="{{ Helpers::url($item->title, $item->id, 'news') }}"><img src="{{ $item->image }}" alt="{{ $item->title }}" class="img-responsive"></a>

                       }}}</figcaption>

                    </figure>
                </li>    
 <li>
                    <figure class="newstyle">
                    <figcaption>{{ $item->created_at }} <a href="{{ Helpers::url($item->title, $item->id, 'news') }}">{{ $item->title }}</a></figcaption>
                        <a href="{{ Helpers::url($item->title, $item->id, 'news') }}"><img src="{{ $item->image }}" alt="{{ $item->title }}" class="img-responsive"></a>

                       }}}</figcaption>

                    </figure>
                </li>
```

I tried it with an for loop but I don't know how it need to be and it gives me some errors

Comment: can you include the errors you are getting in the question. That will help people help you.

Comment: You can do something like `<figure class="<?= $k % 2 == 1 ? 'figure' : 'newstyle' ?>">`